# how to implement redux in angular9?

Tags: angularjs, redux

I am trying to use redux in my application  but I am getting error as:
The target entry-point "@angular-redux/store" has missing dependencies:
 - redux
 - redux-devtools-extension

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can install implement redux in angular by three dependencies.

`npm install redux --save`
`npm install @angular/core --save`
`npm install redux-devtools --save`

Answer (score 1):

As it said,

please install it.

> npm install redux-devtools-extension .

Eventhough its a dev dependency, this we've to install manually

Answer (score 0):

Though they should have come in as dependencies with the initial package install, try manually installing `redux` and `redux-devtools`:

```
npm install redux
npm install redux-devtools
```